# Why my CASE WHEN gave me an AGGREGATION error message?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a promo grouping using one `promo_code` field in a month where there's a chance that a single `customer_ID` would have more than one transaction and could have two different promo code

```
SELECT customer_id AS buyer, 
CASE
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 2 THEN 'Mixed'
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 1 AND flag_promo = 1 THEN 'Promo'
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 1 AND flag_promo = 0 THEN 'Organic'
END AS promo_group
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2
```

It gave me an error message :

`SELECT list expression references column flag_promo which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:41]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT customer_id AS buyer, 
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) > 1 THEN 'Mixed'
    WHEN ANY_VALUE(flag_promo) = 1 THEN 'Promo'
    WHEN ANY_VALUE(flag_promo) = 2 THEN 'Organic'
  END AS promo_group
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -  that's exactly the case - second and third `when` will only be executed if the first one failed - which can be only if `COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 1` - make sense now?

Comment: Good answer +1, I missed that part!

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I think you intended to do:

```
SELECT
    customer_id AS buyer, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 2 THEN 'Mixed'
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 1 AND MIN(flag_promo) = 1 THEN 'Promo'
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT flag_promo) = 1 AND MIN(flag_promo) = 2 THEN 'Organic'
    END AS promo_group
FROM TABLE
WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2;
```

This assumes that a `flag_promo` value of 1 means `Promo` and a value of `2` means `Organic`.  If not, then we can easily edit the above query.